# Matching column to column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

trying to merge/match column to another column in same table

Basically I want ShareID to fall into ShareCategory. so then I could match the categories by average value and and display highest share from its CATEGORY

[image]

output needs to display shareID, ShareNAme, ShareCategorie. But Only Sharenames that have ShareSellPrice ABOVE avarage in their OWN categorie.

Used "Join" command as suggested here by Piyush. Getting 512 msg. 
code im writing looks like this:

```
    select ray.ShareID, ray.ShareName, AVG(ray.ShareSellPrice)
from share_tbl
join share_tbl as ray
on dbo.share_tbl.ShareID = ray.ShareCategory
group by ray.ShareSellPrice, ray.ShareID, ray.ShareName
having ray.ShareSellPrice>
(
    select ray.ShareSellPrice
    from share_tbl

)
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear, please elaborate and post the sample with the desired result.

Comment: what is your desired output???

Comment: output needs to display shareID, ShareNAme, ShareCategorie. But Only Sharenames that have ShareSellPrice ABOVE avarage in their OWN categorie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get average price per category in a subquery and join with the main table on category column and compare the share price with average price to get desired result

```
select s.shareId, s.shareName, s.shareCategory, T.AvgPrice
from share_tbl s
join ( select shareCategory, avg(ShareSellPrice) as AvgPrice
       from share_tbl
       group by shareCategory
     )T 
on s.shareCategory = T.shareCategory
and s.ShareSellPrice >= T.AvgPrice
```

Comment: Thank you! but This returns AVG from whole ShareSellPrice Column, but in this case I need to return shares ABOVE AVG from current Category. e.q IN 1st category I have two SHares, and I need to display the one who is Above AVG in 1st Category.

Comment: @RaySligo, this will return all shrare that are above average in each category. so in 1st category, it will return only share id 1. The sub query is doing average on a share category not on whole table values.

Comment: You are right myfirnd! Its not displaying ShareID 5 tho. Thats the only share in category. Is there a way to show that in table?

Comment: @imhere, share id 5 is the only share in category  3, added >=, so it works even if there is only one share